# SQL IF table A is empty copy columns from table B

Tags: mysql

So here is the perfectly working query I need to run though short of the necessary condition:

```
INSERT INTO content (`id`,`id_pages`,`content`, `date`) 
SELECT `id`, `id`, `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages`;
```

Unfortunately not all the databases are synced properly so some of the tables are populated and some are not.

How do I `INSERT` data from table A to table B `IF` table A is empty?

A couple queries I've tried:

```
IF (
SELECT count(id) FROM content='0',
INTO content (`id`,`id_pages`,`content`, `date`)
SELECT `id`, `id`, `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages`)
```

...as well as:

```
IF (SELECT count(id) FROM content)=0 
THEN (INSERT INTO content (`id`,`id_pages`,`content`, `date`)
SELECT `id`, `id`, `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages`);
```

Comment: Some sample table data would go a long way here.  Can you tell what _relation_ will be used to determine which data gets pulled from `A` into `B` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think sample data matters when question is about logic and syntax and every table is empty in the same way anyway - there are no rows.

Comment: You want to insert table `A` to table `B` if table `A` is empty? But why? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO content (`id`,`id_pages`,`content`, `date`)
SELECT `id`, `id`, `content`, `date_modified` 
FROM `pages`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM content)
```

The `SELECT` of the above `INSERT` statement will return all `pages` records *unless* there is at least on record in `content` table.

[**Demo with empty table**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/466bd/1) | [**Demo with not empty table**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1da1f/1)